# running grep from within GNU make

Tags: regex, makefile, grep

I need to find the text **'ifeq ($(Param1)'** using grep. I try to assign search result to make variable. The problem is that single quotes don't escape text in make so when I try:

```
GrepResult:= $(shell grep 'ifeq ($$(Param1)' TextFile)
```

I get:

```
Makefile:214: *** unterminated call to function `shell': missing `)'.  Stop.
```

The $ can be escaped with $$ but how do I escape parentheses in make?
Thanks.

NB: $GrepResult is used in $(error) function, not in a rule command.

Comment: I'm unable to get that help command to work either.  Have you found a fix?  `$(shell grep ...)`? just use each of grep, awk, sort, pr as lowercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to use $(shell) ?

```
GrepResult:= `grep 'ifeq (\$$(Param1)' TextFile`

all:
  echo ${GrepResult}
```

Tested with GNU Make 3.81.

Comment: sorry, I didn't mention it, but I use grep result with $(error) and with back-quotes it simply outputs the variable contents without executing command.

Answer (score 8):

The trick is to smuggle the special characters past Make *and* grep.

```
GrepResult := ${shell grep 'ifeq (\$$(Param1)' TextFile}
```

Make turns $$ into $, then grep turns \$ into $. Also note that this assignment uses curly braces "{}", not parentheses "()", so as not to be confused by the results of the match. (There may be a more robust way to handle the string, but never mind.)

When you use the result, use single quotes:

```
all:
    @echo '$(GrepResult)'
```

This too was tested with GNUMake 3.81.

**EDIT:**
This also works with $(error...):

```
    $(error '$(GrepResult)')
```